# How to save the login code that i get from telegram app to login into Telegram?

Tags: c#, api, telegram

Actually when i use to execute my program , each time i need new login code to login into Telegram.So i need help in this regard that login code should be saved and not to feed each time the new login code.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TLSharp.Core;
namespace Telegram
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        string hash = String.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string code = textBox2.Text;
        TelegramClient client = Utility.Client;
        var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("SENDER_MOBILE", hash, code);
        var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();
        //find recipient in contacts
        var user1 = result.users.lists.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser)).Cast<TLUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.phone == "RECEIVER_MOBILE");
        //send message
       // await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = user1.id }, "Hiii,Welcome to Telegram");
        this.Hide();
        Form2 ss = new Form2();
        ss.Show();

    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Utility.Client = new TelegramClient(APP_ID, "APP_SECRET");
        TelegramClient client = Utility.Client;
        await client.ConnectAsync();
        hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("MY_MOBILE_NUMBER");
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }


   } 
}
```

Comment: Don't execute button1 each time you login.  button1 returns a new hash over-writing the old hash.

Comment: How it work if i don't execute button1?Kindly elaborate more.

Comment: hash is in global space will use hash from the first time button1 is executed.